# Wrap anchors in list tags in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some code like this:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

and I want to rewrite it using jQuery to produce:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul id="carousel">
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What's the best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pB98T/

```
$('#gallery > a').wrapAll('<ul id="carousel">').wrap('<li>');
```

This wraps all the `<a>` elements with the `<ul id="carousel">` [using `.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/), then wraps them individually with `<li>` [using `.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: I wonder if there is a performance difference between this method and Nicks?

Comment: @Kamikaze - I'd say this is a little more efficient because it doesn't require the `.parent()` traversal. The amount of wrapping taking place in both is identical.

Comment: It depends, it'll be very, very close, but as always, test! http://jsperf.com/gallery-wrap-test

Comment: @Nick - Surprising that the extra traversal is faster in some browsers. I tried to run tests in IE, but it gives me the slow running script warning. Any idea how to disable that?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$("#gallery a").wrap("<li />").parent().wrapAll("<ul id='carousel' />")​
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DQUSQ/2/) (added some CSS to see the result clearer).  Remember to call [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) after [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), since [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) returns the original element (the `<a>`, not the new `<li>` parent).

Answer (score 0):

one line:

```
$('#gallery').wrapInner('<ul id="carousel"/>').find('a').wrap('<li/>');
```

or two lines:

```
$('#gallery a').wrap('<li/>');
$('#gallery').wrapInner('<ul id="carousel"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#gallery a').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<li  class="liclass"/>');
});

$('.liclass').wrapAll('<ul class="ulclass"/>');
```

Refer : **[.wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap)** , **[.wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)**

you can test its functionality **http://jsbin.com/iluxe4**